# Search on DateOnly or TimeOnly Object in Razor Pages

Tags: c#, razor-pages

I am new to ASP.net and working on Razor pages(ASP.net 6.0)
My model consist of following attribute

```
 public class TestModel
 {
  public string? Name{ get; set; }
  public DateOnly? Date { get; set; }
  public TimeOnly? Time { get; set; }
}
```

and on Form,
I am have multiple search option. I want to search only for Date or Time provided by user.
I am unable to get the Query for Date Only and and Time only.
For instance my query is for search name is as follows:

```
 IQueryable<TestModel> TestQuery = from m in _context.TestModel

---
Model
                                select m;
 if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searcStr))
 {
     TestQuery = TestQuery .Where(s => s.Name!= null && s.Name.ToLower().Contains(searcStr.ToLower()));
 }
```

Date and time format in DB :
Date: 2023-09-03
Time: 01:39:20

User is entering in same format.

All Date and time only functions doesn't help to search.
Any help would be appreciated

I tried date as string and also `Date.Equals ,Date.Value` function.

**Update: Solution that worked for me**

```
 DateOnly dateOnly = DateOnly.FromDateTime(DateStr);
 TestQuery = TestQuery.Where(s => s.Date != null && 
 s.Date.Equals(dateOnly));
// and for time 
 TimeOnly timeOnly = TimeOnly.FromTimeSpan(TimeStr);
 TestQuery= TestQuery.Where(s => s.Time != null && 
s.Time.Equals(TimeStr));
```

Thanks for the response.

Comment: `"I want to search only for Date or Time provided by user"` Hows your user poviding date and time? Whats the format? How this data field looks like in database can you include same data or format?

Comment: In addition, need to have a look at your search string and how your date time column designed in database and how the values are existed there its important to share.

Comment: Dates have no format, they're binary values similar to numbers. All date/time picker controls return their *values* as DateTime or Timespan at least. That means you can easily write `_dbContext.Sales.Where(s=>s.SaleDate==dateFromPicker)`

Comment: The current query is bad too and should be replaced with just `query.Where(s=>s.Name.StartsWith(searchStr))`. Applying functions to table fields prevents the use of indexes. `s.Name != null` is pointless because the other comparisons eliminate NULLs. In SQL, any comparison to NULL fails and is treated as False. You could just write `s=>s.Name.Contains(input)` BUT that translates to `NAME LIKE '%somename%'` which can't use indexes either. `s.Name.StartsWith(searchStr)` on the other hand translates to `LIKE 'somename%'` which is treated as a range search between this prefix and the next larger

Answer (score -2):

```cs
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searcStr))
{

    TestQuery = TestQuery.Where(s => s.Name!= null && 
    s.Name.ToLower().Contains(searcStr.ToLower()) || s.Date.Value.ToString().Contains(searcStr) ||    s.Time.Value.ToString().Contains(searcStr));
}
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Comment: This is not working for me. I tried it. It throws runtime exceptions.

Comment: Dates aren't strings. This query can't be translated to SQL and even if it did, the *localized* string comparisons would result in bad results and the worst possible performance - applying functions to fields prevents the use of indexes